# Magento upgrade deleted admin design and skin files

Tags: magento-1.9

I have performed a Magento version upgrade (from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.10) using the `mage` shell script. The upgrade completed without throwing any error, but it deleted all the admin files in app/design and skin.

Did anyone experience this? How can I fix it?

Thank you